# How to use ES6 modules in web workers inside React app with webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, web-worker, es6-modules

I want to use web workers in my app.

This is my worker:

```
import { processOrderFieldValue } from './utils';

export function colsAndRowsWorker() {
  this.onmessage = () => {
    processOrderFieldValue();
    // in this place the compiler is trying to convert this module to this:
    //Object(_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["processOrderFieldValue"])
    //and I've got this:
    //Uncaught ReferenceError: _WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not defined



    postMessage('oops');
  };
}
```

I also tried to use `importScripts('./utils')`, but also got an error.
How to use modules in worker inside the React app? Perhaps, I can define the function as a relative path in importScripts()?